# enable scroll in Scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

So i created a ScrollView containing multiple views, but the scroll doesn't work and i can't display the other views, does anybody have an idea how i could do it or what's wrong with my code?
here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import {ScrollView,View,Text,Button,StyleSheet,FlatList,Image} from 'react-native'
export default function MedProfilScreen({route}){
    const {name,specialite,work}=route.params;
    return(
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1,alignItems:'center'} } >
        <View style={styles.ctr1}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={require('../assets/Title.jpg')} />
          <Text style={styles.txt}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.txt}>{specialite}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.txt}>{work}</Text>
          <Button title='Prendre rendez-vous' onPress={()=>{}} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>fgfg</Text>
          <Text>fgfg</Text>
          <Text>fgfg</Text>
          <Text>fgfg</Text>
          <Text>fgfg</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove flex:1 from your contentContainerStyle, using it is like doing this

```
<ScrollView>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   some content
  </View>
<ScrollView>
```

Which ends up taking only available space and removing the scroll functionality as the content isn't bigger than its container